# Can we use Posgresql with Parse-Server without PostGis?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, parse-server

I'd like to use parse server. I can only get Postgresql and no PostGis. Will it work or is PostGis absolutely necessary?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Not yet, however I have to be sure that it works if I run an application on it and I can't fool myself with a false pretence. That's why I'm asking in case anyone knows it.

Comment: I think you'll get an answer easier by spinning up a Postgresql server somewhere locally, installing Parse and trying to do things with it.

Comment: I believe you will need the PostGis to run the geo queries. If you don't plan to use them, you should be good without it, but I agree that the best way to verify would be just running it and trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

@Davi is correct, it will run just fine without Postgis, but if you need geo query's you will get errors. If you plan on using postgres/postgis for parse through docker, it's pretty easy,

```
docker run -d --name parse-postgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password --rm postgis/postgis:11-3.0-alpine && sleep 20 && docker exec -it parse-postgres psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE parse_server_postgres_adapter_test_database;' && docker exec -it parse-postgres psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis;' -d parse_server_postgres_adapter_test_database && docker exec -it parse-postgres psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;' -d parse_server_postgres_adapter_test_database
```

This info is for testing, but it's the same setup, https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#run-postgres-setup-for-parse-with-docker

Info on how use to use the postgres URL will be in the documentation soon as an update is pending [here](https://github.com/parse-community/docs/pull/731), but here's the updated https://github.com/parse-community/docs/blob/1285886bcfcae47ca8b1850b8a8d45b8450e08fa/_includes/parse-server/database.md#postgres